# Show the result of module as either pop up or in new page

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I have created a module in my joomla site which accepts the roll number and output the result . the problem is that it shoes the result within the limits of module position whereas i want it to show either in pop window or in new page . 
Please have a look at here

http://www.vtubuddy.com/index.php/disclaimer.html

module check result. plese use usn=3PG07CS020

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

Create new component 
(can be only one .php file with all the code you already have in your module, that pull data from db a echo it and add Jrequest listener for your USN number).
Redirect you button in your module to the link with your component with POST method and USN number.

Here you can find simple component tutorial:
[enter link description here](http://www.vojtechovsky.net/joomla/component-helloworld-tutorial-guide-en.html)

If you dont want to create new component, you can use JUMI extension. Just create new article, put your php code into this article and link your button in module to this new article.